# Kubernetes dashboard via GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, kubernetes-dashboard

Sorry to bother you, but i am having a serious issue with my online DevOps learning.
In fact, i am taking a Devops course and we are using the google cloud platform as a cloud. When i create my cluster with gcloud container clusters create xxx and then do the describe command like gcloud container clusters describe xxx, it works but i have no information regarding the login and password to Kubernetes;
That is one of the problem.

After creating the cluster, i got not Kubernetes dashboard link with the command kubectl cluster-info. Normally i should have a Kubernetes dashboard to manage my app. In place of having the Kubernetes dashboard, there is something called Kubernetes system metric.

Can somebody help me fix this problem probably someone who is used to practice on GCP.

Best regards

Comment: [Kubernetes GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes), what do you get when hitting this link?

Comment: It goes to my GCP clusters, the one with the numbers of nodes;

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go through this Google Cloud Kubernetes dashboards docs[1]?

Because, I'm able to see Kubernetes dashboard in my console. But, I don't know why you are not able to see that, and I also checked there is now any service outage on Kubernetes from Google Cloud Status Dashboard[2]. But, It's working fine. So, kindly go through that Kubernetes docs, from that you will get some better understanding of working with Kubernetes in GCP.

If you're still facing any issue or abnormal behavior, please go to public issue tracker[3] or support from GCP console and raise a ticket.

[1]. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards

[2]. https://status.cloud.google.com/

[3]. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Comment: Thanks, i am going to explore these recommendations and let you know

Answer (score 0):

When you visit the [GCP dashboard docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards), you should see red warning on top of the website, saying:

> **Warning**: The open source Kubernetes Dashboard addon is deprecated for clusters on GKE and will be removed as an option in version 1.15. As an alternative, use the Cloud Console dashboards described in this guide.

[Below](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards#kubernetes_dashboard) you read:

> Starting with GKE v1.15, you will no longer be able to enable the Kubernetes Dashboard by using the add-on API. You will still be able to install Kubernetes Dashboard manually by following the instructions in the project's repository. For clusters in which you have already deployed the add-on, it will continue to function but you will need to manually apply any updates and security patches that are released.

To deploy it, follow the instructions on [k8s dashboard github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard)